# How can I break blocks remotely?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to break blocks far away (e.g. A piece of glass 50 blocks away) with commands, but I don't know if there's any way.

Is it possible to break a block (literally break a block, which means with sound & with particles) with a command? Or should I use the `/particle` `/sound` and `/fill` command to "break" the block? (`/particle` will create the glass-breaking particle, `/sound` will play the glass-breaking sound, and the `/fill` command will fill the glass with air.)

Comment: Wild idea, not even remotely sure if it is possible. But a very localized explosion without sound? Or that not possible?

Comment: I tried to use `/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:1,Direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}`but it cannot break obsidian, and it causes a very loud explosion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should do it.

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:air 0 destroy
```

From [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock):

> ***destroy*** — The old block drops both itself and its
> contents (as if destroyed by a player). Plays the appropriate block
> breaking noise.

Comment: I did not expect this option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ air 0 -` making sure that the chunk the block is in is loaded.

Alternatively, put the `/setblock` command in the spawn chunks so that no matter where you go it will destroy the block. This is because when you reach the chunk and load it in, the command block will perform the setblock command.