# How to make a block show a breaking animation using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking a command that makes a block look like it's being mined by a player. Not `/setblock` or `/fill`, which makes the block disappear instantly.

For example, in Hypixel's Blocking Dead when you shoot a block with a gun, it looks like it's being broken. It could be that they use a texture pack for the blocks breaking, but it doesn't seem likely.

I have not tried to do this myself, but have searched for awhile.

Comment: Do you mean the block break particles, or the cracking animation texture?

Comment: `fill replace`. Use the wiki.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I break blocks remotely?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192383/how-can-i-break-blocks-remotely)

Comment: @pppery That does not appear to be the case, the question is asking how to make a block show its "breaking" animation, not to break the block entirely.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing.

Popular servers like Hypixel and Mineplex don't use Vanilla Minecraft commands. They actually use something called [plugins](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Plugins) which are actually programmed with Java. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on the internet where you can actually do this with *commands*, but Hypixel definitely used plugins for this game. If you're trying to emulate what Hypixel is doing, I'm afraid I have to break the news that you probably can't (or it would be really, really hard to) do what you're wanting to do.

There may be a solution, but I am alerting you of what Hypixel does

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, with a fair bit of work.  One way would be to repurpose some blocks for this.  I'm not a command expert, so you'll have to fill in some of the details yourself.

Say, you have a jungle motif, and don't care about sandstone blocks.  You want a cobblestone block to move to "hit, but not destroyed" then to "destroyed."

You replace the cobblestone block with a sandstone block with your custom texture to make it look like a "hit but not destroyed" cobblestone block.  Then, whenever a "hit but not destroyed" block is hit, you replace it with air.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cracked version of 3 blocks: stone bricks, nether bricks and blackstone, so you can use those 3, but if you really want to do something like cobblestone just change the cracked stone bricks texture for example to cracked cobblestone.

If I find something we can do with commands I'll let you know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fill replace` to break the block with particles instantly.

However the cracking animation as you mine blocks can't (to my knowledge) be replicated with commands.

You can also use `particle` to make the particles appear when blocks are being mined.